# Kingston SSD Secure Erase not working

Tags: partitioning, ssd, secure-erase

I have a hard drive that I cannot Secure Erase because there is still partitioning in the drive, but there are not any partitions left shown in disk 2 in the disk management tool, yet its not letting me secure erase. Would I have to delete the main partition as well or would this cause problems for my harddrive?

[image: screenshot Kingston SSD Manager]

[image: screenshot SSD has no partitions]

Comment: Setting the drive offline in Disk Management might help. (Right click on the `Disk 2` / `Online` box.)

Comment: Or use `clean` in `diskpart` first.

Answer (score 0):

The `F:` partition is still allocated.

Right-click the partition in Disk Management and select
"Delete Volume".

Comment: I did now I have two blocks of Unallocated Space and it does not work still

Comment: Do a quick-format in Disk Management of Disk 2.

Comment: Still does not work

Comment: After the format the whole disk should be one unallocated space. Please add a screenshot of Disk Management for your current situation.